Why is the prohibition against coveting (לא תחמוד) considered to be the greatest and most difficult commandment?
While writing an answer to the question of whether the War of Gog and Magog has occurred already (https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/143162/7303), a very significant idea was mentioned, which originated from Rabbi Moshe Chaim Luzzato about one of the primary objectives related to Moshiach being involved in that war.
That idea is that this war is principally aimed at the objective of correcting the damage, the consequences from the sins of Adam and Kayin. That Adam caused death to exist in this world and Kayin caused murder to exist in this world and they are the root causes behind war and conflict.
Based on the order of what Ramchal writes there, it appears that the sin related to Kayin, which is violating the prohibition against coveting (לא תחמוד) is the first priority, even before the sin of Adam. Kayin coveted what his brother, Hevel had, and the consequence was murdering his brother. In fact, Isaiah 11:6-9, which says:

The wolf shall dwell with the lamb. The leopard shall lie down with the kid; the calf, the beast of prey, and the fatling together with a little child to herd them.
The cow and the bear shall graze. Their young shall lie down together; and the lion, like the ox, shall eat straw.
A babe shall play over a viper’s hole, and an infant pass its hand over an adder’s den.
In all of My holy mountain nothing evil or vile shall be done; for the land shall be filled with devotion to G-d, as water covers the sea.

also pertains to this. Many of the aspects of predation and the predator/prey relationship seem to relate to the subject of repairing the damage from Kayin.
Many years ago, a similar question was posted to this website and closed for lack of details and clarity. Here is one answer that attempted to consider the subject. Perhaps it will provide some suggestions for thought to anyone who wishes to tackle this question today. https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/67013/7303
In particular, it should be noted that the second half, five of the ten commandments relate directly to the prohibition against coveting. Additionally, it is the last of the ten in order and their summation.

+1. I believe Ramchal explains why the lust for honour, which is the root cause of coveting, is the most difficult sin in Chapter 11 of Mesilat Yisharim. I will bli neder write an answer if I have time and nobody beats me to it, but in the meantime go have a look. It's towards the end of the chapter, one of the last sins discussed. Rabbi Friedman also discusses it in certain shiurim, if I find one I'll share as a comment

@RabbiKaii Please don't limit your answer to addressing Ramchal in Mesilat Yesharim. It's relevant, but there is much more. If you want to focus on Ramchal, make sure you go through the Tikkunim Chadashim that I linked to. Remember, this has to pertain to the Tikkun of the whole creation.

@RabbiKaii Remember, what is occurring right now in Israel, what occurred on October 7th, Shemini Atzeret/Simchat Torah in Israel is part of this.

There's not much question in this question.

@shmosel That all depends on who is looking. If you would like some suggestions, trying looking into Sifri and other Midrash pertaining to the ten commandments and their order and the meaning of the order. Also, the idea of did we hear only 1 commandment or 2 directly? If 2, which 2 are we to consider and how does that change in regard to this question?
